# Did anything changed in google fit api. My AppScripts code is not working

Tags: google-api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

it's throwing this error: TypeError: Cannot read property "dataset" from undefined.

Earlier dataset is recognizable and starting October 28th, I am getting the above error. 
Background: I am using this dataset from google fit api for collecting my step count for previous day and it's a job that runs everyday in the morning to gather this data.